# Serialize different XML with equal node count and type, but different node names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is there any way to use one class for 2 or more XML file serialization, if XMLs have the same amount of nodes with the same value types?

E.g.

```
<root>
   <element1> string </element1>
   <element2> int </element2>
<root>

<root>
   <otherElement> string <otherElement>
   <otherElement2> int </otherElement2>
</root>
```

I would like to serialize them both like following class objects:

```
public class root
{
   public string stringElement {get; set;}
   public string intElement {get; set;}
}
```

I could use Linq to XML, to make the XML's match the class, but I'm trying to find efortless solution. Is there something like [XmlElement("element1") **or** ("otherElement")]?
Hope you understand what I'm trying to ask and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be usefull

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335724.aspx

you can create special XmlSerializer with names you need